# jPlayer - play series of mp3 files with poster

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jquery-plugins, jplayer

I'm trying to modify the jPlayer QuickStart project to play a series of mp3 files sequentially, each one with its own poster image.  This is basically just using html, JavaScript,  jQuery and CSS.

(QuickStart is here, for reference: http://jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/)

Below is my current code, which is not working (not playing even the first mp3 or audio file).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var m = [{
        mp: "data/audio1.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide1.PNG"
    }, {
        mp: "data/audio2.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide2.PNG"
    }, {
        mp: "data/audio3.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide3.PNG"
    }];
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $.each(m, function(index, value) {
                alert(value.mp);
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: value.mp,
                    poster: value.p
                }).jPlayer("play");
            });
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        size: {
            width: "960px",
            height: "720px"
        }
    });
});
```

The **alert(value.mp);** is telling me I am getting the file names ok.

I have tried it with and without the **jPlayer("play")**, no luck either way.

If I remove the **each** line, and just use something like **m[0].mp** and **m[0].p**, I can play any given mp3 and display any given PNG. But the "each" approach is not working to play each of the mp3 files sequentially along with its associated image.

I know that jPlayer has a listplayer add-on, but it has a lot of functionality I don't need, so I'd rather not use it if I can do this with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've worked out to play the mp3s and display the associated posters sequentially.  It's based on the jPlayer **ended** event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var m = [{
        mp: "data/a24x2x1.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide1.PNG"
    }, {
        mp: "data/a24x3x1.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide2.PNG"
    }, {
        mp: "data/a24x4x1.mp3",
        p: "data/Slide3.PNG"
    }];
    var n = 0;
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended, function(event) {
                if (n < m.length - 1) {
                    n++;
                } else {
                    alert("do something after the last slide");
                    return;
                }
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: m[n].mp,
                    poster: m[n].p
                }).jPlayer("play");
            });
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: m[n].mp,
                poster: m[n].p
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        size: {
            width: "960px",
            height: "720px"
        }
    });
});
```